# How do mining pools fetch and retrieve blockchain data? How could one start their own?

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools

I was just wondering how the various cryptocurrency mining pools are fetching the live transaction data, such as merkle trees, block hashes, etc. I am new to mining, but a great programmer, so I had implemented about as fast of a bitcoin miner I could get on my old 2012 iMac, which can run at almost 2MH/s (faster one newer processors, but it's still a CPU, so, now much better I can get). However, I'd like to know how the hosts of these large pools are actually submitting and retrieving the data to/from the connected miners. This is because my hardware is so old and slow that most pools don't even recognize my worker due to the great discrepancy between my hardware and that of others. I'm not looking to make some great amount of money, but just a way to have fun mining without being rejected due to considerably low hash rate.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear what your goal is, do you want to connect a CPU miner to a real live BTC mining pool (will never happen) or solo-mine on the live network with a CPU (guaranteed fruitless) or create your own isolated pool as a way of exploring software design?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Protocols for use between mining clients and mining pool servers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13307/13866)?

Comment: I have a bitcoin miner attached to a pool already, but what I'm wondering is: when I submit a nonce to the pool, where is the pool submitting it?